# Wrong to use AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I have a view(MVC3) that users place orders from. The view is bound to a model that i use to display modelitems from. There are two functionalities on this view. First you enter the customers details and then you choose the items the user has ordered. This is the code i´m using to build another model to be sent back to serverside:

```
var modelItems = {
    ModelID: [],
    Amount: []
};

var serviceModel = {
    Name: $.trim($('#name').val()),
    Customernumber: $.trim($('#customernumber').val()),
    Address1: $.trim($('#address1').val()),
    Address2: $.trim($('#address2').val()),
    Zipcode: $.trim($('#zipcode').val()),
    City: $.trim($('#city').val()),
    Country: $.trim($('#country').val()),
    Phone: $.trim($('#phone').val()),
    Mobile: $.trim($('#mobile').val()),
    Email: $.trim($('#email').val())
};

$('div.modelSpan').each(function (i) {
        var textBox = $(this).children();
        var value = $(textBox).val();

        if (value != '0' && value != '') {
            var modelID = $(textBox).attr('name');
            modelItems.ModelID.push(modelID);
            modelItems.Amount.push(value);
        }
    });

var accessory = {
            ModelItems: modelItems,
            ServiceModel: serviceModel
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Site/Order', //Renamed sec reasons
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(accessory),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (ordernumber) {
                window.location.href = "/Site/OrderInfo/" + businessAB + "/" + ordernumber;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
```

Cool thing in MVC3 is that my accessory automatically binds to my model on serverside called AccessoriesModel. On callback success i´m setting new href to a receipt site to show user what has been created. This all works but my issue is that i would like the receipt view(OrderInfo) to be returned from my controller that receives the [httppost] and not setting new href. Is there a way to do this? This is easy when using regular form submit but because the values for my model dont come from one form it complicates things. Maybe I shouldn´t use AJAX?

Comment: what about generate partial view and return it from controller using ajax?

Comment: if i use the partial view wont it just load on the same page where the ajax post was sent?

Comment: Just hid the div containing partial view and then after ajax success showed partial and hid rest of content

Answer (score 0):

You could use knockout JS with Ajax and render your pages with a mixture of JavaScript objects and regular html.